# As3: Event listeners don't work with Child

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, listener

I'm new posting here,
I'm making a game with flash professional. I want to add in a movie clip on the stage a button from the library so I've used addChild. All right, the code works but the event distendersi don't.
My code is here:

```
vFsOnM.x = -47, 45;
vFsOnM.y = 119, 5;
vFsOnM.width = 243, 05;
vFsOnM.height = 30, 80;
vFsOffM.x = -47, 45;
vFsOffM.y = 119, 50;
vFsOffM.width = 243, 05;
vFsOffM.height = 30, 80;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_checkFS);

function fl_checkFS(event: Event): void {
    if (vFS == 0) {
        menu.mIn.addChild(vFsOnM);
        if (contains(vFsOffM)) {
            menu.mIn.removeChild(vFsOffM);
        }
    }
    if (vFS == 1) {
        menu.mIn.addChild(vFsOffM);
        if (contains(vFsOnM)) {
            menu.mIn.removeChild(vFsOnM);
        }
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.FULLSCREEN, fl_fsDetectM);

function fl_fsDetectM(event: FullScreenEvent): void {
    if (stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.NORMAL) {
        vFS = 0;
        menu.mIn.addChild(vFsOnM);
        if (contains(vFsOffM)) {
            menu.mIn.removeChild(vFsOffM);
        }
    }
    if (stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN) {
        vFS = 1;
        menu.mIn.addChild(vFsOffM);
        if (contains(vFsOnM)) {
            menu.mIn.removeChild(vFsOnM);
        }
    }
}

menu.mIn.vFsOffM.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_fsSM);
    function fl_fsSM(event: MouseEvent): void {
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
        vFS = 0;
    }
menu.mIn.vFsOnM.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_fsAM);
    function fl_fsAM(event: MouseEvent): void {
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
        vFS = 1;
    }
```

I hope the code is pasted correctly because I'm using my tablet.
Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You reference your movieclips differently:

```
menu.mIn.vFsOffM
```

and just

```
vFsOffM
```

Using addChild does not add the instance name of the child as a property to the parent.
If vFsOffM is the instance name that you use to identify the object, it will stil lbe the reference to that object no matter to what parent you addChild it to.